# Splitting up a large file into smaller files at specific points

Tags: python-3.x

I know this question has been asked several times. But those solutions really don't help me here. I have a really big file (5GB almost) to read, get the data and give it to my neural network. I have to read line by line. At first I loaded the entire file into the memory using .readlines() function but it obviously resulted in out-of-memory issue. Next I instead of loading the entire file into the memory, I read it line by line but it still hasn't worked. So now I am thinking to split my file into smaller files and then read each of those files. The file format that for each sequence I have a header starting with '>' followed by a sequence for example:

```
>seq1
acgtccgttagggtjhtttttttttt
tttsggggggtattttttttt

>seq2
accggattttttstttttttttaasftttttttt
stttttttttttttttttttttttsttattattat
tttttttttttttttt

>seq3
aa

.
.
.

>seqN
bbbbaatatattatatatatattatatat
tatatattatatatattatatatattatat
tatattatatattatatatattatatatatta
tatatatatattatatatatatatattatatat
tatatatattatatattatattatatatattata
tatatattatatattatatatattatatatatta
```

So now I want to split my file which has 12700000 sequences into smaller files such that for each file with header '>' has it's correct corresponding sequence as well. How can I achieve this in python without running into memory issues. Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: A couple questions: In your example, some of the `>` have a space after them, some do not. Is this how the file looks as well, or is it more standardized? In your title you said "at specific points" -- how are you wanting to cap the new files (e.g. after a certain character count, after so many sequences, etc.)?  I can see accomplishing this with a while loop inside of the for loop, but there are probably more clever methods using a schema and indexing.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake while writing this example. So it's without space. I've edited as well. So I was thinking that each file has 5000 sequences. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you explain what went wrong with your line by line approach, and maybe post the code? If you're doing that properly there shouldn't be any difference compared to reading `n` smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with 12,700,000 randomized lines with 1-20 random characters in each line. Though the size of my file was far less than 5GB (roughly 300MB)--likely due to format. All of that said, you can try this:

```
x = 0
y = 1
string = ""
cycle = "Seq1"
with open(f"{FILEPATH}/main.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0] == ">":
            if x % 5000 == 0 and x != 0:
                with open(f"{FILEPATH}/Sequence Files/Starting{cycle}.txt", "a") as newfile:
                    newfile.writelines(string)
                cycle = f"Seq{y*5000+1}"
                y += 1
                string = ""
            string += line
            x += 1
        if line[0] != ">":
            string += line
    with open(f"{FILEPATH}/Sequence Files/Starting{cycle}.txt", "a") as newfile:
            newfile.writelines(string)
```

This will read the file line-by-line, append the first 5000 values to a string, write the string to a new file, and repeat for the rest of the original file. It will also name the file with the first sequence within the file.

The line that reads `if x % 5000 == 0:` is the line that defines the number of sequences within each file and the line `cycle = "Seq" + str(y*5000+1)` creates the formatting for the next filename. You can adjust the 5000 in these if you change your mind about how many sequences per file (you're creating 2,540 new files this way).

Comment: I used your code. But it ends up giving my bunch of files with just one line of sequence without any header or anything. And I don't seem to understand why that is. I do get files where I have headers with their corresponding sequences but most of the files has just one line of sequence.

Comment: The problem is in the last sequence or 5000th sequence being read. It reads the header and then the first line sequence and every other line of the sequence is then being written in different files thus creating files with just one line of sequence instead of the whole sequence.

Comment: Check your indentation. I'm not able to replicate this. It could have something to do with formatting of the input file, but without seeing it, it's pretty difficult to diagnose.

Comment: indentation is correct. I doubled checked. How do you propose I share my input file. It's pretty big. Formatting is exactly what I gave in the example. The only difference is that there are no empty lines in the file. But it shouldn't make a difference based on the code you've written since you're incrementing only when '>' is encountered.

Comment: So I managed to solve the problem partially. If I add x = 1 inside of if-statement block then I get rid of files with just one line of sequence. But the problem of last sequence of every file being split still persists. So I have header and the first line of sequence in one file and the rest of the sequence is the beginning of the next file.

Comment: I think I've figured out the bug. For each file, code stops writing when x==5000 which means that every time 5000th time it had already read the line after '>' header line and then the if-statement will be true and so rest of the lines will not be read.

Comment: Added two more lines to the end to finish it out--you're right, it was ending prematurely.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because of what I said before. But thanks patmcb :) I'll figure out a way around it.

Comment: 17th time's a charm? I was able to replicate the problem by adding extra lines in the input file between the sequences. So I've attacked the problem a different way. It seems to be working with just about any input I throw at it. Updated code in the answer.

Comment: Yes it's working now. I did something of the same sort. Thanks @patmcb.